# ReSharper turning all text pink

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

Recently I've installed the Jetbrains product ReSharper for Visual Studio and seem to be having some issues. I've installed it before on a different device and had no issue. It seems to be turning all text pink.

Example:
[image: pink text example]

Is their some setting I have missed or option I can change?

Thanks

Comment: It seems like class members are colored with the pink color? Is this the default color scheme? Do the colors look differently on the other device with the same color scheme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `ReSharper`->`Options`->`Code Inspection`->`Settings`, untick `Color identifiers` to turn off ReSharper's colouring.

[image]